# MVC Manually reset string still passes required validation on refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public class LoginModel
{        
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }        
    private string password;
    [Required]
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = Hash(value); }
    }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public LoginModel RemovePassword()
    {
        Password = null;       
        return this;
    }
}

public ActionResult Login() { return View(); }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Models.LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (CurrentUser.Login(model.Username, model.Password)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); }
        }
    }
    return View(model.RemovePassword());
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {                        
        <div class="modal-header">                  
            <h3 class="modal-title">User Login</h3>
        </div>                                      
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="@usernameFormGroup">  
                <label for="textboxUsername" class="ie">Username</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Username, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "textboxUsername", @placeholder = "Username", autocomplete = "off" })                    
            </div>
            <div class="@passwordFormGroup">  
                <label for="textboxPassword" class="ie">Password</label>                                    
                @Html.PasswordFor(o => o.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "textboxPassword", @placeholder = "Password", autocomplete = "off" })                                                     
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">        
            <button id="buttonForgotPassword" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Forgot Password?</button>                
            <button id="buttonLogin" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>  Login</button>
        </div>                        
    }
```

So essentially, when a login failure is encountered, it removes the password box as most sites will. I also have in place an IP lockout for failures.

After a failed login, if I refresh the page, it posts back and the empty password box still passes through the required validation - even though it is empty, and adds another login failure for the user. Is there a better way to essentially reset the password box so it is set as invalid?

Does refreshing the page repeat the previous post? If so, there may just be no way to avoid this from happening.

Comment: could you add your controller code and your Login View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the original question so removing prior answer details as it clouds the topic with unnecessary information.

The original question really is "what is the behavior of browsers when you F5 refresh them after posting data to the server results in an error."

The browser will generally (tested in IE and Chrome) prompt you asking whether you want the data you previously posted to be posted again and this is the reason they form passes validation. Hitting refresh doesn't post the visible form data but the form you posted on the prior post.

Comment: Ah nice.  I figured I was trying to reinvent the wheel there.  I'm still trying to figure out why it doesn't re-invoke the validation if you refresh the page though.  After a failed login, it returns the model, and shows you have so many login attempts remaining before it locks you out.  Everytime you do this, it seems it's posting back and some how passing required validation.  It also did this after I added your simplification with the attribute.

Comment: How are you "refreshing" the page. Are you clicking the login button again with an empty password field or are you hitting refresh in the browser?

Comment: F5 refresh.  Is it posting back with the prior form?

Comment: When you hit F5 on a form that you "posted" it tells you it is going to re-send the information your did previously. IE and Chrome have similar behavior where they prompt you about re-posting the form's data. Debugging I see the same values being posted so yes it is posting the prior form.

Comment: Yea that's what I was starting to think.  I guess my user's are just SOL if they keep refreshing that page.  Thanks for the help Lukis.